# json data does not appear

Tags: android, json, ionic-framework, laravel-5

im currently using ionic framework for android and laravel
why is that when my json data is with bracket is not being displayed

```
[{"name":"Steve","state":"CA"}]
```

this below works just fine

```
{"name":"Steve","state":"CA"}
```

here is my controller

```
.controller('TestController', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('http://192.168.10.33/api/data').then(function(resp){
    console.log('Success', resp);
    $scope.name = resp.data.name;
    }, function (err){
    console.error('ERROR',err);
    }) })
```

i use

```
{{name}}
```

to display on html file the json data

Comment: did you use ng-repeat?

Comment: var obj = [{"name":"Steve","state":"CA"},{"name":"prabhu","state":"cc"}];
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
  console.log(obj[i].name)
}

Answer (score 0):

Since your data (resp.data) is an array, not a single object, this line:

```
$scope.name = resp.data.name;
```

Should probably be

```
$scope.name = resp.data[0].name;
```